# Codeigniter app in shared hosting can't connect to remote mysql in vps

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, vps, shared-hosting

I have a MySql DB in my VPS that can access by remote. I already try this tutorial to open remote my DB in VPS. [This is the link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-remote-database-to-optimize-site-performance-with-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04)

then, I have a CodeIgniter application that must be connected to that MySql DB.

There are the scheme:

1. The CodeIgniter app in my **localhost**, set the DB configuration to that MySql DB. **It Work**
2. The CodeIgniter app in my **Shared hosting**, set the DB configuration to that MySql DB.   **Error**

I attach the error log, below here

[image]

Comment: Then it must be something wrong with your configuration. Recheck the IP address, the username, password and database name you're trying to access.

Comment: Hmmm. Might be relevant to mention the environments. What operating system, PHP versions, etc on the different environments? Is cPanel and/or mod_security or something similar installed on any of the environments?

Comment: @Fredster The IP address, username, password, and database name setting in my localhost and VPS are same, cause it use same application.

Comment: @Goose I use Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 5.6. I use Vesta CP. I am still search the solution in other place. I am assume it cause by mod_security or firewall in my VPS. If you have any clue / solution / question, I would like to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

firewall of the server must be set-up to enable incomming connections on port 3306
you must have a user in MySQL who is allowed to connect from % (any host) (see manual for details)
The current problem is the first one, but right after you resolve it you will likely get the second one.

Comment: I am still search how to set up the VPS firewall. If you have any clue, I like to hear it.